# IsInArray not returning True when it should

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am using the IsInArray function to check if a cell address (Row,Column) exists within an array. For some reason, even though the array contains the value it doesn't match. For example if my array is like this:

```
18, 812, 84, 34, 412, 87, 74
```

And `OldRow & OldCol` gets to `34`, the function `IsInArray` doesn't match it and execute `Else`.

Below is a sample of the code I am using to try and achieve this:

```
    Set c = .Find(1, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            cellAddress = c.Address
            OldRow = Range(cellAddress).Row
            OldCol = Range(cellAddress).Column

            If IsInArray("OldRow & OldCol", mappedcells) = False Then
                oldmappingrow = Application.Match(OldRow, Worksheets(1).Range("r3:r16"), 0)
                If Not IsError(oldmappingrow) Then
                    OldRowMapped = Worksheets(1).Range("r3:r16").Cells(oldmappingrow).Offset(, 1).Value
                End If

                oldmappingcol = Application.Match(OldCol, Worksheets(1).Range("r3:r16"), 0)
                If Not IsError(oldmappingcol) Then
                    OldColMapped = Worksheets(1).Range("r3:r16").Cells(oldmappingcol).Offset(, 1).Value
                End If

                If OldCol > OldRow Then
                    NewCol = WorksheetFunction.Max(OldRowMapped, OldColMapped)
                    NewRow = WorksheetFunction.Min(OldRowMapped, OldColMapped)
                Else
                    NewRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(OldRowMapped, OldColMapped)
                    NewCol = WorksheetFunction.Min(OldRowMapped, OldColMapped)
                End If

                .Cells(NewRow, NewCol) = .Cells(OldRow, OldCol).Value
                .Cells(OldRow, OldCol).Value = "0"

                ReDim Preserve mappedcells(UBound(mappedcells) + 1) 'Add next array element
                mappedcells(UBound(mappedcells)) = NewRow & NewCol          'Assign the array element

                Set c = .FindNext(c)
                Debug.Print (OldRow & OldCol & " moved to " & NewRow & NewCol)
            Else
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
            End If
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
```

And the `IsInArray` function I am using:

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0))
End Function
```

Sorry if the code is messy and could be written cleaner, I am totally new to vba and programming as a whole. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"3" & "4" <> 34` but `"3" & "4" = "34"` and `Int("3" & "4") = 34`. Try it as,

```
 If not IsInArray(clng(OldRow & OldCol), mappedcells) Then
```

As noted in the comment from [Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner) below, go through your code and make sure you are comparing numbers to numbers or text to text and not numbers to text-that-looks-like-a-number.

Comment: One more note, the OP will need to change `stringToBeFound As String` in the function to `stringToBeFound As Variant` for the same reason.  The long will be turned back into a string and a match will not be found.

Comment: It didn't work when I used `clng(OldRow & OldCol)` but did when I just took away the quotes and used `OldRow & OldCol`. Thanks for your help guys! +1